# C++ how can I create an array of objects when there is a constructor?

Tags: c++, arrays, object, constructor

If `myClass` does not have a constructor the following works fine:

```
myClass x[5];
```

If I put a constructor in `myClass` this line results in a compiling error.

What is standard practice for creating an array of objects when a constructor is defined?

Is  it possible to  populate the entire array of objects with a single constructor?

Comment: If you define a default constructor that code will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If myClass does not have a constructor the following works fine:

This is if your class has no *user-declared constructor*. In that case it has an *implicitly-declared default constructor*, which is what will be used by

```
myClass x[5];
```

to construct the objects.

If you declare a constructor yourself, the implicit default constructor will not be declared. Instead you can declare your own. A default constructor is just a constructor that can be called without arguments:

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {
        // Default constructor
    }
};
```

or, if you just want the default constructor to behave exactly as the implicit one would, you can *default* it:

```
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() = default;
};
```

If you don't want to do that and use a different constructor, you may still be able to use list initialization:

```
myClass x[5] = {{/*constructor arguments for first object*/},
                {/*constructor arguments for second object*/},
                //...
               };
```

Or, easier, just use `std::vector<myClass>` and `push_back` or `emplace_back` each element with the constructor arguments that you need.

```
std::vector<myClass> x;
x.emplace_back(/*constructor arguments for first object*/);
x.emplace_back(/*constructor arguments for second object*/);
//...
```

which can also be done in a loop, or, if all all objects are supposed to be copies of one another:

```
std::vector<myClass> x(5, myClass(/*constructor arguments*/));
```

Comment: The default constructor can also be defined as `myClass() = default;' if the compiler-generated constructor is adequate. +1.